# I can't insert data in a table weird error mysql

Tags: mysql, insert

Hello I have a table called 'comisiones' described as follows:
[image]

when I try to insert a new element with this query:

```
INSERT INTO comisiones (id,serial,descripcion,fecha,precio) VALUES (0,"111111111111111","Iphone 5 instalacion de aplicaciones","09/06/2016",2000);
```

I get this error:

> `INSERT INTO comisiones (id,serial,descripcion,fecha,precio) VALUES (0,"111111111111111","Iphone 5 instalacion de aplicaciones","09/06/2016",2000)`
>   Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'fecha' in 'field list'

with SHOW CREATE TABLE comisiones; I get this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `comisiones` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `serial` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
   `descripcion` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
   `fecha` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
   `precio` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

Comment: If you have a missing column error it stands to reason the column is missing or labelled incorrectly. Is it possible there's a space in that column name? Additionally, note that dates should be in [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. What you have here could be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Hi @tadman I deleted and create that column again to make sure there's no spaces also note that is varchar field not date and in the insert I'm sending a normal string text

Comment: If it's a date, store it in a `DATE` column. There's no reason to store it as text, that will be impossible to work with.

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` say for this? That usually exposes any errors. If you can, edit and amend your question with that data.

Comment: I edited the output @tadman

Comment: That should work according to your schema description. Are you sure you're running the query against the correct database? I've had situations like this where I'm inadvertently connected to the wrong one and run queries against an older schema missing a column.

Comment: Another thing that might be a factor is that [`SERIAL` is a reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) so you may need to delimit that in your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I replace serial by imei and still  the same error =(

Comment: @tadman From your own link: *Nonreserved keywords are permitted as identifiers without quoting*. `serial` is keyword but not reserved.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Just looking for potential problems here.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself I had to delete the table and create it again and now is working fine